# How to match a GPS location to a map area?

Tags: android, ios, gps, windows-phone

After the latitude and longitude numbers are obtained from a GPS device, I need to check if this device is by a lake or a river, which is a fairly large area.

I could store a series of GPS locations along the river as an array in the database. If the detected location is close to any value in the array, I would decide the user is along/on the river.

This method is awkward. And it has trouble when it comes to a lake. A user may be inside a lake on a boat, with a location far away from the lake border.

So, what is a preferred solution to decide if a GPS location is close to a river/lake?

Comment: No way. Are we to throw beacon along a river? And the center of a lake can well be farther than 10m away from a lake side beacon

Comment: Never do that but as per my aspect Beacon is the only best option in your case. becoz you already failed with GPS or Network location. Do radius based calculation i mean if you're in 10m of radius then you're Very near to Boat.  Beacons already provide this

Comment: Can you put the point on a map, like Google Maps and check the color of the location? If it's blue or very close to blue, your inside the lake/river.

Comment: very creative. but how to get the name of the river/lake?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The correct way is to use a point in polygon algorithm.
Digital map provideres offer polygons for water areas, like lake or river.

There are line based water structures (middle line of small river), and polygon based. These polygons have a name attached.

The difficult (or expensive) part is to get the polygons.
If you dont have a contract with the both major digital map provideres (TomTom and Here) you can only try OpenStreetMap.

Comment: Thank you. I guess the polygon may be worth to try.